# Filtering nullable items in the List - LINQ

Tags: c#, linq

I have the following List item in order to display. I could visualize the small list follows, that could be hundreds rows. `StartDate` and also `EndDate` can be `nullable`, if `EndDate` is null, it means the course still open.

```
CourseId    ClassName    StartDate   EndDate      isActiveinDB
--------    ---------    ---------   -------      ------------
12321       Math         08-25-2017  12-02-2017      Y
32342       Math         08-25-2017  12-02-2017      N
25325       Math         01-25-2018     -            Y
```

If I pass today date (06-06-2018) in the following method, it returns me all courses rather than only the last course (Math 25325) which has not expired and open based on `isActiveinDB`.

I wonder what is not correct with the following implementation.

```
public List<Courses> GetClassesByDate( DateTime date, List<Courses> allCourses)
{
   List<Courses> courses  = allCourses.Where( x => x.StartDate.HasValue ? x.StartDate <= date : true 
                            && x.EndDate.HasValue ? x.EndDate.Value >= date : true 
                            && x.isActiveinDB.Equals("Y")).ToList();
   return courses;
}
```

Thanks to @DavidG, implementation is in the following [link](https://dotnetfiddle.net/nXmDWx)

Comment: You are missing a qualifier in your lambda `&& isActiveinDB.Equals("Y")` should be `&& x.isActiveinDB.Equals("Y")`

Comment: @DavidG, I forget to add it, but it is in the code already, apologize for the typo. Sorry David.

Comment: Then your code is perfectly fine as it stands.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try (if `StartDate` is nullable, as you said):

```
List<Courses> courses  = allCourses.Where( x =>  
                        (x.StartDate.HasValue ? x.StartDate.Value <= date : true)
                        && (x.EndDate.HasValue ? x.EndDate.Value >= date : true) 
                        && x.isActiveinDB.Equals("Y")).ToList();
```

You see the `()` I've added? I thing what you are doing is actually

```
x.EndDate.HasValue ? x.EndDate.Value : (true && isActiveinDB.Equals("Y"))
```

You see? The `true` isn't a single value, but is a subexpression `true && isActiveinDB.Equals("Y")`

Comment: Okay, your update clears it up.  I couldn't immediately see how your code fixed the problem.

Comment: Actually I think this is still wrong, OP is just missing the `x.` before `isActiveinDB` so is likely using an internal variable.

Comment: that's why I always put parenthesis even if they are not needed

Comment: Now OP has added the `x.` to the question, I don't think the code given to us is not working. The parentheses added here do not make any difference to the output.

Comment: @hotspring [Using the exact code you post above proves it works fine](https://dotnetfiddle.net/14tcWZ)

Comment: @DavidG, kudos to your amazing effort! Let me check one more time before adding paranthesis.

Comment: @hotspring You should still include the parens though, it makes the intent far clearer anyway

Comment: @David, just realized that `StartDate` can be nullable as well. I have made changes. Therefore, could you please analyze the following implemetation https://dotnetfiddle.net/nXmDWx

Comment: @hotspring Well that does change the question and make this answer correct. Please be more careful in future when posting code and try to produce a [mcve]

Comment: @hotspring You love to forget putting `()`? you should put them in both ternary subexpressions...

Comment: I apologize David, but still need to know why that make these changes. why does it affect?

Comment: @hotspring Try adding an element `new Courses(25325, "Test", new DateTime(2018, 01, 25), null, "N"),`... It shouldn't be outputted, but it is...

Answer (score 1):

Operators are in an order to be evaluated in a expression. It is explained in https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2bxt6kc4.aspx. There's a table that shows operators in the order in a table.

As you can see in the list, conditional expression (?:) is quite low priority. So, I recommend to put parenthesis any time around the conditional expression, then you can avoid such accident as you have.

The following code is NUnit test code for verifying the operators order. Hope Record class is close to your case.

Executing this test, the first assertion passes but the second one fails. It proves the parenthesis makes difference in such expression.

```
[TestFixture]
public class SyntaxTest
{
    public class Record
    {
        public string Id;
        public DateTime? StartDate;
        public DateTime? EndDate;
        public string isActiveinDB;
    }

    [TestCase]
    public void TestConditionalSyntax()
    {
        var list = new List<Record>
        {
            new Record { Id = "0000", StartDate = DateTime.Parse("2018-01-01"), EndDate = DateTime.Parse("2018-06-01"), isActiveinDB = "Y" },
            new Record { Id = "0001", StartDate = DateTime.Parse("2018-01-01"), EndDate = DateTime.Parse("2018-09-01"), isActiveinDB = "N" },
            new Record { Id = "0002", StartDate = DateTime.Parse("2018-01-01"), EndDate = DateTime.Parse("2018-08-01"), isActiveinDB = "Y" },
            new Record { Id = "0003", StartDate = DateTime.Parse("2018-01-01"), EndDate = null, isActiveinDB = "Y" },
            new Record { Id = "0004", StartDate = DateTime.Parse("2018-08-01"), EndDate = null, isActiveinDB = "Y" },
            new Record { Id = "0005", StartDate = null, EndDate = DateTime.Parse("2018-06-01"), isActiveinDB = "Y" },
            new Record { Id = "0006", StartDate = null, EndDate = DateTime.Parse("2018-08-01"), isActiveinDB = "Y" },
        };

        var date = DateTime.Parse("2018-06-15");
        var result1 = list.Where(x => ( x.StartDate.HasValue ? x.StartDate <= date : true )
                                 && ( x.EndDate.HasValue ? x.EndDate >= date : true )
                                 && x.isActiveinDB.Equals("Y")).ToList();
        Assert.That(result1.Count, Is.EqualTo(3));

        var result2 = list.Where(x => x.StartDate.HasValue ? x.StartDate <= date : true
                                 && x.EndDate.HasValue ? x.EndDate >= date : true
                                 && x.isActiveinDB.Equals("Y")).ToList();
        Assert.That(result2.Count, Is.EqualTo(3));
    }
}
```